# Is there a nice GUI available for showing Hibernate statistics?

Tags: hibernate, user-interface, grails, statistics, metrics

Hibernate exposes many internal metrics via the [Statistics API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-monitoring-metrics). Is there an easy-to-use GUI that I can use to visualize these statistics? Bonus if there is a Grails plug-in for this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two plugins: http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-stats and http://grails.org/plugin/app-info which includes Hibernate stats.